# contao 4.4 - how to congfigure a multilanguage instance

Tags: contao

I want to create a multilanguage site in contao.
What I did so far:

At first I copied the Page tree of current language.
At second I added domains like example.com/de and example.com/en in site-structure "Domain name" of both root pages.

Edit: Finally I added app/config/config.yml

```
contao:
    prepend_locale: true
```

For my assumption it should work now but it doesnt.
What else is necessary to make it work.

Comment: I got no clue about `php`, but I suppose you lack **code**. How do you suppose people help you if you don't share the code describing your problem? Please create a reproducable code example of your problem! Check the points under ['Help others reproduce the problem'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As this is a contao problem everybody who works with contao 4.4 has this code :) This question is more about configuring/ handling code and knowing where to make adjustements

Answer (score 0):

In your case you do not configure any DNS names for your website roots, since you are using only *one* domain. Instead, you should use the following in your `app/config/config.yml`:

```
contao:
    prepend_locale: true
```

Clear and warmup the production cache afterwards. This will generate URLs like `example.com/de/…` and `example.com/en/…`.

See also https://github.com/contao/core-bundle#configuration

Comment: i forget to mention that i also did that. I edited the question.

Comment: Did you delete and warmup the cache? What exactly "does not work" now?